# Problem in the plotted array, which is the dft of a signal

Tags: python, matplotlib, fft, dft

I have an array including the sample values of a signal (121 samples). However, when I want to plt the Discrete Fourier Transform of it, I take this plot:
[image]

This is the related part of my code:

```
sp = np.fft.fft(flow)
n = np.arange(len(flow))
timeStep = 1
freq = np.fft.fftfreq(n.shape[-1], d=1)
plt.plot(freq, sp.real)
```

According to the plot every time, the plotted figure has two values. But, this is not sensible and possible. When I print the arrays, everything looks OK. Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot.

P.S.:
The real part of sp matrix is:

```
[ 4.62700000e+04 -2.64892524e+04  4.94317914e+03  8.58381182e+03
 -2.05540197e+03  1.53516262e+03 -1.30716540e+04  1.74769311e+04
 -1.13435074e+04 -3.79140600e+03  6.94722233e+03 -2.55937762e+03
  2.62187832e+03 -7.91539720e+03  1.07849088e+04 -1.86067707e+02
 -8.81467635e+03  5.39181241e+03  4.67386587e+03 -1.16464162e+04
  2.25400000e+03  3.43226092e+02 -2.18100065e+03 -6.91513328e+03
  7.67106151e+02  6.32196523e+03 -1.11715436e+04  3.84865629e+03
  4.89120922e+03 -3.04642885e+03 -1.75000000e+02  2.98504637e+03
  2.46837686e+03 -2.87114353e+03 -5.14905071e+02  4.95859846e+03
 -2.79387832e+03 -3.71433195e+03  5.20579454e+03  3.77109275e+01
 -1.31300000e+03 -2.36758839e+02  4.66440953e+03  4.50017683e+03
 -8.51326995e+03  9.20006771e+03  3.47394048e+03 -7.50148888e+03
  4.57289385e+03  2.52869599e+03 -3.16622233e+03 -2.08767047e+03
  9.15962695e+02  1.44698611e+03 -8.07662141e+03  6.76627369e+03
 -8.90969316e+03  6.48281486e+03 -3.46137363e+03 -3.44706367e+03
  6.48400000e+03 -3.44706367e+03 -3.46137363e+03  6.48281486e+03
 -8.90969316e+03  6.76627369e+03 -8.07662141e+03  1.44698611e+03
  9.15962695e+02 -2.08767047e+03 -3.16622233e+03  2.52869599e+03
  4.57289385e+03 -7.50148888e+03  3.47394048e+03  9.20006771e+03
 -8.51326995e+03  4.50017683e+03  4.66440953e+03 -2.36758839e+02
 -1.31300000e+03  3.77109275e+01  5.20579454e+03 -3.71433195e+03
 -2.79387832e+03  4.95859846e+03 -5.14905071e+02 -2.87114353e+03
  2.46837686e+03  2.98504637e+03 -1.75000000e+02 -3.04642885e+03
  4.89120922e+03  3.84865629e+03 -1.11715436e+04  6.32196523e+03
  7.67106151e+02 -6.91513328e+03 -2.18100065e+03  3.43226092e+02
  2.25400000e+03 -1.16464162e+04  4.67386587e+03  5.39181241e+03
 -8.81467635e+03 -1.86067707e+02  1.07849088e+04 -7.91539720e+03
  2.62187832e+03 -2.55937762e+03  6.94722233e+03 -3.79140600e+03
 -1.13435074e+04  1.74769311e+04 -1.30716540e+04  1.53516262e+03
 -2.05540197e+03  8.58381182e+03  4.94317914e+03 -2.64892524e+04]
```

The flow is:

```
 [    0.     0.     0. ...     0.  2611.  2984.]
```

Comment: "According to the plot every time, the sp.real array has two values" - the plot in the post clearly shows that there are more than 2 values, though

Comment: @ForceBru - I believe OP is referencing the horizontal line running across the bottom.

Comment: @BigBen Thanks, by OP you mean SP (in my code)? if yes, I just had followed the sample code in numpy.org: t = np.arange(256)
sp = np.fft.fft(np.sin(t))
freq = np.fft.fftfreq(t.shape[-1])
plt.plot(freq, sp.real, freq, sp.imag)

Comment: @BigBen https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fft.html#numpy.fft.fft

Comment: @Maryam, OP is you - the Original Poster. You can check the shape or size of your array to see how many values it contains: `sp.real.shape`.

Comment: @ForceBru it is (121, 1)

Comment: @Maryam, this means that there are `121 * 1 = 121` values in the array.

Comment: @ForceBru Yes, that is true.

Comment: @Maryam, "the `sp.real` array has two values" - so, not two values. Or am I maybe misunderstanding something?

Comment: @ForceBru I might write it in a vague way. Actually, sp.real is an array containing 121 elements. And I want to plt them. However, when I run my code I take the above plot, which shows in time t, the plotted array has got 2 values, which is wrong.

Comment: @BigBen I have added the sp.real array as well as the flow.